# How to iterate if list contains unequal tuple in size?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If we have a list which contains equal tuple in size then we can iterate through like below:

```
list1 = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
for (i, j) in list1:
    print(i, j)
```

What if I have a list of tuple as below?

```
list1 = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5), (7, 8, 9), (10, 11)]
```

Instead of using a nested `for` loop, is there any other way to iterate through all elements?

Comment: Why is a nested `for` loop not an option? Is there some other problem we can help with which means that you can't use them?

Comment: Yes, why not for loop? Any other other option will iterate internally to get the result.

Comment: If the inner lists always have the same size as your example, you can ask if `i` is pair or odd to know if the size is 2 or 3 and you can avoid the for loop, bat only works for that example

Comment: `for x in list1: ...`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you already know the minimum size, you can unpack the minimum and the remainder:

```
>>> list1 = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5), (7, 8, 9), (10, 11)] 
>>> for i, j, *r in list1:
...     print(i, j, r)
... 
1 2 [3]
4 5 []
7 8 [9]
10 11 []
```

Answer (score -1):

You can unpack the tuple and convert it to a list and use `len()` on `list` to get its `size` without knowing it beforehand:

```
list1 = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5), (7, 8, 9), (10, 11)]

for elem in list1:
    print([*elem], "of size: {}".format(len([*elem])))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3] of size: 3
[4, 5] of size: 2
[7, 8, 9] of size: 3
[10, 11] of size: 2
```

If you dont want any list conversion:

```
print(', '.join(map(str, (elem))), "of size: {}".format(len(elem)))
```

Output:

```
1, 2, 3 of size: 3
4, 5 of size: 2
7, 8, 9 of size: 3
10, 11 of size: 2
```

Comment: why transforming it to a list if you can call `len` on the tuple?, it can be done like this: ```>>> for elem in list1:
...     print(f"[{', '.join(str(e) for e in elem)}], of size {len(elem)}") ```

Comment: @Netwave just thought it'd be pretty looking, added an edit to it. Thank you!

Comment: The only problem with the other code is that you are building 2 unnecessary lists. Those are some little tips that helps on making python to run quicker :)